# Storing values for a vector<vector<int>> elements on a separate container

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following structure in my code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> elems;
```

and each element in elems (i.e. each vector of ints) has a certain double value I need to keep track of. Elements do not have any unique feature that could be used as key in a map (I tought of using their pointers, but the elems vector keeps growing and being shuffled during the program so their address change).

Considering this, I thought of creating a class containing a vector and a double and modifying the structure in this way:

```
std::vector<MyClass> elems;
```

thus having the value straight there, but I don't know much this would affect performances.
Does anyone have better solutions or can point me to somewhere where I could find some more information about this case?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: That is a 2D vector, not a 1D vector as you claim in your second sentence. Moreover, you mention a double value, but the data type is `int`.

Comment: It's unlikely to affect performance in visible manner, however the only way to tell is to actually implement both versions and measure. Unless you profile your code and notice that your class affects performance, just don't worry about it.

Comment: @gsamaras Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough. The main structure is, as I said, a vector<vector<int>>, and each element of the outer vector (i.e. each vector<int>) has a double value that is different (even if it is related) from the various int it contains.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought of creating a class containing a vector and a double and modifying the structure in this way:
>
> ```
> std::vector<MyClass> elems;
> ```

That's absolutely valid and a reasonable choice to group the `double` value together with a collection of integers. I'd suggest using a plain `struct` like this

```
struct DoubleAndVec {
    double value;
    std::vector<int> vec;
};
```

and take a minute to think about good names, they are essential here (`MyClass` e.g. could be improved as well as `DoubleAndVec`).

When it comes to performance, don't think about it until you encounter a bottleneck. If you do, profile and check whether this design choice has any implications on your program performance - I heavily doubt it.

Comment: I'll try following this way then, thank you! (And names were obviously a placeholder :D)